# How to add default parameter in stored procedure and increment it automatically?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure which has two parameters : week, year. When I execute the stored proc, it asks for the week and year and after giving those values, it displays certain result. Now, what I want to do is, I want to get the results from 1st week of 2014 to the current week.

```
This is my code,

    USE [MyDatabase]
    GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySP] 
@Week int,
@Year int
AS
BEGIN
exec (Another Stored Procedure from another database)
END
```

So, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL has a `while` statement you could use:

```
declare @current_week int = datepart(week, getdate())
while @week <= @current_week
    begin
    ... do stuff ...
    set @week = @week + 1
    end
```